# How to change DateFormatter to timeStamp in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, timestamp

For example, I want to change NSDateFormatter object like this "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm" to timestamp, is anyone has good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First covert the date string to NSDate, then use timeIntervalSince1970 to get the timestamp.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-10-12 10:30";
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSDate *formattedDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString: dateString];

NSTimeInterval timestamp = [formattedDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: Do not use `YYYY` for the year, use `yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeIntervalSince1970. Try it:

```
NSString *mydateString = @"2010-7-5 1:39";
NSDateFormatter *Df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
[Df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];   

NSDate *formattedDate = [Df dateFromString: mydateString];

NSTimeInterval mYtimestamp = [formattedDate timeIntervalSince1970];

NSLog(@"Hello my time: %f--",mYtimestamp);
// To get it back:
NSTimeInterval _interval=mYtimestamp;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"date again-:%@",dateString);
```

Comment: Do not use `YYYY` for the year, use `yyyy`.